# Height of View inside tableviewcell differs from ios 7 and ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `uiview` inside the `tableviewcell`. When i run the code with ios 8 the table `cell` look good and working fine. But when i try to run this code in ios 7 the table `cell` contents overlapping on the other content of the `cell`.

Can anyone help me to  do that correctly.

Attached the Tableviewcell scrrenshot as follows:

[image: view contents overlapping eachother]

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(!self.customCell){
    self.customCell = [self.goalDetailsTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsCell"];
}

//Height of cell
float height = 360;
return height;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hemang - Actually this relates to my last question but the problem is on the iOS 7 version, I am getting the image as shown above. Also remove the duplicate flag and -1

Comment: @Hemang Do u have any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by myself.

When you are running in ios7, just set `maskToBounds = YES` in tableViewCell implementation file.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.cardDetails.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```